# How to remove relation from @ManyToMany association using Hibernate from not owner side?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have 2 entities which associated by `@ManyToMany`. First is owner of relationship. I need to update second: remove from it old relations to First and add new.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private Set<Group> groups;
}
```

and second

```
@Entity
public class Group {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private Set<Person> person;
}
```

As you can see the `Person` is owner in this relationship. I need to update some Group. In input data i receive `Group` id and set of id of `Person`, which I need to add to this `Group`. Previously i need to remove all `Person` from this `Group` (only from this `Group`, not totally remove). So I try to clear `Set` of persons, then add new persons and then persist `Group`. Also I try to do same but persist `Group` after clear set of persons and after add new persons to this list. In both cases only new persons add to `Group`, without removing old from it.

**UPD**

I know about 2 ways how to do that: 1 Run native SQL Query and 2 remove relation from owner side. I'll try to find easiest way

Comment: You are required to maintain both sides of a bidirectional relationship in JPA, so it would be good practice to not just clear the list, but go through and modify each Person so that the group is removed from their list as well.  Because these Persons are then detached from the group, you will need to merge each change individually to have it picked up.  The alternative is that you make the Group.person set own the relationship instead, so that changes to this set control the relationship in the database.  Caching will not be maintained and you have the same problem from the other side though.

Comment: @Chris - I think your comment is worth writing it as a whole answer. It explains the discrepancy between object-oriented approach of entities and relational approach of SQL, which is many times not realized. In addition to your comment, it is also possible to call JPQL query with update, but it will not refresh already loaded Person entities.

Answer (score 0):

This would be far easier to do with SQL

```
DELETE from Person_Group where GroupId = ?  //Empty group
INSERT into Person_Group values (?,?)       //Add new member
INSERT into Person_Group values (?,?)       //Add new member
INSERT into Person_Group values (?,?)       //Add new member
...
```

I would recommend using this approach. It is much easier to implement.

The Hibernate of doing it is to get all Persons (both the old group members and the new ones) in memory (by Id) and update their memberships.

Comment: If you use JPA/hibernate, it is better to use equivalent JPQL queries, so that you may take advantage of the object-relation binding.